# How to run a OpenQASM 3.0 file?

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience, qasm

When uploading a QASM-file with `ÒPENQASM 3.0;` as first line, the code editor on quantum-computing.ibm.com will throw an error.

However the qiskit Python library doesn't support the new features (e.g. for-loops) of OPENQASM 3 either.

So where can I run an OPENQASM 3.0 file?

Comment: Welcome to the quantum computing stack exchange ! I want to point out that openquasm 3.0 is still in development and a work in progress. It may therefor be not supported by other languages like qiskit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenQASM3 is in an early release stage for circulation for feedback in the quantum community. OpenQASM3 aims to be a standardized language proposal for near-term quantum computing hardware with real-time computing capabilities. We hope that it will lay the foundation for extracting tangible benefits from real quantum computers in the coming years by providing a straightforward interface for research in error-correction, classical/quantum algorithms, and control techniques. Information about the language can be found in the [live specification](https://qiskit.github.io/openqasm/). It is expected that this will evolve quite rapidly in the coming months. We value all feedback and accept issues or pull requests being submitted on the [language specification repository](https://github.com/Qiskit/openqasm).

A formal grammar and accompanying parser should be available shortly and will be found in the language repository. Work has begun to add support for the new functionality introduced in OpenQASM3 in Qiskit, simulators, and hardware backends. As support is rolled out it will be announced.

Comment: So does openqasm3.0 actually work now or is it just a concept?